# how to pass multiple url parameters in django

Tags: python, django

I have 2 links in my html templates. First link pass only 1 parameter to URL and second link pass 2 parameters. Like this:

```
<a href="/products/{{categ_name}}">{{categ_name}}</a>
<a href="/products/{{categ_name}}/{{subcateg_name}}">{{subcateg_name}}</a>
```

Now when i click on link with 1 parameter it works fine. I get the parameter value in my django view.
 But When i click on link with two parameters i only get the first parameter. I get None in the value of second parameter.

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
            url(r'^products/(?P<categ_name>\w+)/', views.products, name='products_category'),
            url(r'^products/(?P<categ_name>\w+)/(?P<subcateg_name>\w+)/', views.products, name='products_subcategory'),
            url(r'^logout/',views.logoutView, name='logout'),)
```

My views.py:

```
def products(request, categ_name=None, subcateg_name=None):
    print categ_name, subcateg_name
    ...
```

How to get the value of second parametre?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Change your urls to:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
            url(r'^products/(?P<categ_name>\w+)/$', views.products, name='products_category'),
            url(r'^products/(?P<categ_name>\w+)/(?P<subcateg_name>\w+)/$', views.products, name='products_subcategory'),
            url(r'^logout/',views.logoutView, name='logout'),)
```

Then, you avoid your 2-parameter url being matched by the first 1-parameter pattern. The $ special character means end of string.

Comment: Side note: It's also possible to simply re-order the URL patterns so that the more specific one is listed first. Django processes URLs on [first-match-wins](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request) basis. Explicitly adding the anchor is probably cleaner, though.